# Performing row update within Select By Location based on field within selected feature class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, select-by-location, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to select address points from address feature class within a selected zip code from zipcode feature class and populate the address feature class field "ZipCode" with the "Zip_Code" field from the zipcode feature class that is selected.  What I have so far doesn't produce an error, but continues to run and the ZipCode field is not being populated.

I am new to python.

Following is what I have so far.

```
#Set variables for feature classes
addresses = "Addresses"
zipcodes = "Zip_Codes"

#Perform Select by Location to create the zipcode data from ZipCodes to Addresses
#Create layer file
address_layer = "addr"
zipcode_layer = "zip"

if arcpy.Exists(zipcode_layer):
    arcpy.Delete_management(zipcode_layer)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(zipcodes, zipcode_layer)
result = arcpy.GetCount_management(zipcode_layer)
print("There are {0} zip codes in the Zip_Codes feature class".format(result))

if arcpy.Exists(address_layer):
    arcpy.Delete_management(address_layer)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(addresses, address_layer)

#Update zipcode field in Addresses feature class based on selectbylocation on Zip_Codes
#Initiate count to 1
count = 1
fieldListA = ["ZipCode"] #Zip code field from addresses variable
fieldListZ = ["Zip_Code"] #Zip code field from zipcodes variable
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(addresses, fieldListA) as upCursor:
    for row in upCursor:
        #Select all address points within the selected Zip_Code field within zipcode_layer
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(address_layer, "WITHIN", zipcode_layer)
        result = arcpy.GetCount_management(address_layer)
        #print("There are {0} addresses".format(result))

        strZip = row[0]
        upCursor.updateRow(row)

        count = count + 1
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and remove this image, and instead copy and paste your code using code blocks?  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like you want to populate a field in the adress layer with the number of selected features and not the actual zip codes from zip_code layer.

You are not assigning a value to row, so `upCursor.updateRow(row)` will do nothing. An assignment is for example:

```
row[0] = 12345
```

If you want to fetch the zip code from overlapping zip code polygon you can do i with a cursor inside the cursor, se code below. I dont recommend this on large data sets since it will have to go through all polygons for each Point. You should use  [Spatial Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) tool instead.

```
import arcpy

address = r'C:\database.gdb\adresses'
zipcodes = r'C:\database.gdb\zipcodes'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(address, ['SHAPE@','zipfield_to_update']) as ucursor:
    for update_row in ucursor:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(zipcodes, ['SHAPE@', 'zipfield_to_read']) as scursor:
            for search_row in scursor:
                if update_row[0].within(search_row[0]):
                    update_row[1] = search_row[1]
                    ucursor.updateRow(update_row)
```

You could also do this on selections, like you try in your code and it will propably be quicker.

Comment: I am new to python, so I am sure I have it built wrong.  I do want to populate a field in the address layer with the actual zip code - not the number of selected features.

Comment: @Sandy: There is no need for a script, use Spatial Join: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm

Comment: If you actually want to do it your way you would need a search cursor within the updatecursor to read the zip code of the selected features. But dont do that when there is spatial join

Comment: I need to use this in a script that will be ran after hours.

Comment: You can use Spatial Join in a script

Comment: Thank you BERA, I thought I may have to add a search cursor within the update, but I couldn't find a good example of how to do it.  I will research and test some more.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet below you create a row object named `row` on the second line, and then on the last line you update the cursor row using the current value of `row` which you have not modified in between.  You have read the first item in `row` when you did `strZip = row[0]` but you have not written anything to it.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(addresses, fieldListA) as upCursor:
    for row in upCursor:
        #Select all address points within the selected Zip_Code field within zipcode_layer
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(address_layer, "WITHIN", zipcode_layer)
        result = arcpy.GetCount_management(address_layer)
        #print("There are {0} addresses".format(result))

        strZip = row[0]
        upCursor.updateRow(row)
```